# need help iterating through array generated by yaml (php)

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, yaml

**I'm creating a symfony2 application that searches and replaces strings from files**

I created a yaml file with the following content:

```
parameters:
         file.search_and_replace:
                 "path/dir/filename":
                        replace: 'word'
                        with: 'anotherword'

                 "path_2/dir/filename_2":
                        replace: 'apples'
                        with: 'oranges'
```

now to fetch the content I use the following syntax:

```
$array = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('file.search_and_replace');
```

If I dump the variable like this:

```
var_dump($array);
```

it returns

```
array(2) 
{
  'path/file/filename' =>
    array(2) 
    {
      'replace' => string(4) "word"
      'with' => string(11) "anotherword"
    }
  'path_2/file/filename_2' =>
    array(2) 
    {
     'replace' => string(6) "apples"
     'with' =>    string(7) "oranges"
    }
}
```

I need to find a way to loop through this array
so I can pass the content to a function I created, that needs the following parameters:

```
searchAndReplace('filepath','replace_this_word','with_this_word');
```

something like:

```
foreach($array as $file)
{
    searchAndReplace($file.path,$file.replace,$file.with);  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close.

Two things:

1. [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) can accept a `key => value` syntax. Using this you can get
   the *path*.
2. PHP does not use *dot notation* for arrays. It uses
   brackets.

Try the following:

```
foreach ($array as $path => $sub) {
    searchAndReplace($path,$sub['replace'],$sub['with']);  
}
```